# sqlplus and Ruby

Tags: ruby, sqlplus

Anybody knows how to use sqlplus in ruby?
I need to do something like this:
system("sqlplus username/pwd@database filename.sql"

Thx
/Niklas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get sqlplus to read its input from a file you need to prefix the filename with an `@` symbol. So the following would work:

```
system("sqlplus", "username/pwd@database", "@filename.sql")
```

`system` can either be called with a single argument (your complete command) or multiple arguments (with the arguments to your command separated out as in the above example). The [documentation for Kernel#exec](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005971) describes the difference (`system` behaves in the same way):

> If `exec` is given a single argument,
>   that argument is taken as a line that
>   is subject to shell expansion before
>   being executed. If multiple arguments
>   are given, the second and subsequent
>   arguments are passed as parameters to
>   command with no shell expansion. If
>   the first argument is a two-element
>   array, the first element is the
>   command to be executed, and the second
>   argument is used as the `argv[0]` value,
>   which may show up in process listings.

**Note:** If you want sqlplus to exit and return to your ruby program after running the SQL then make sure you include a `quit` statement at the end of your SQL file.